# SELECTING multiple rows by 2 columns

Tags: php

```
  [         POSTS         ]
  | id |   title  | class |
  |----|----------|-------|
  | 1  |   4567   |    2  |
  | 2  |   1234   |    1  |
  | 3  |   9124   |    1  |
  | 3  |   9124   |    w  |
  ________________________
```

How can i `SELECT` multiple `class column` values and sort it to be `echo`ed in `HTML` like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = :id"
$statment= $conn->prepare($query);
$statment->execute([':id' => $id]);

while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
$title1 = $row['title']  //WHERE THE CLASS IS 1
$title2 = $row['title'] //WHERE THE CLASS IS 2

echo"
<a>$title1</a>
<a>$title2</a>
}
```

How do specify which title appear by its class? i already used the `id` but i want to use the `class` like

```
$title1 = $row['id'], AND $row['class'] = 1
$title2 = $row['id'], AND $row['class'] = 2
$titleo = $row['id'], AND $row['class'] = w
```

to sort it `while echo` or do i have to go

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = :id AND class = 1"
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = :id AND class = 2"
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = :id AND class = 'w'" //FOR STRINGS
```

Comment: Use group by `class` and display only `title`

Comment: @Niklesh Do i use `group by` inside the query? because that wouldn't work as intended, Since i'll have many `<a></a>` with different `classes` and some of these `classes` are `strings`

Comment: Are you going to allow Titles with multiple class values to be shown more than once?

Comment: @M31 Yes, for something like `related:`  `1234, 9124` `and you may like` `4567` - as `echo "related: $title1 and you may like $title2"`; for a topic selected by its `GET_ id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE class in (1,2,'w') ORDER BY class ASC
```

This will give you all the posts with the class values within the In () statement. It will show each record separately which means you will have two rows for titles which have multiple class values. Since it looks like you want to separate them using PHP that should be ok. Then you can do that in your while loop like:

```
$classes = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
  if(!isset($classes[$row['class']])){ $classes[$row['class']] = array(); }
  $classes[$row['class']][] = $row['title'];
}
```

This would give you arrays of Titles for each class:

```
[
   1=>[1234,9124]
   2=>[4567]
   'w'=>[9124]
]
```

Then you can output them all in order of the class or by class:

```
foreach($classes as $key => $class){
   echo "Class Value: ".$key; // just to show the order
   foreach($class as $title){ echo "<a>".$title."</a>"; }
}
```

Which will wind up giving you:

```
Class Value: 1
<a>1234</a>
<a>9124</a>
Class Value: 2
<a>4567</a>
Class Value: w
<a>9124</a>
```

I am not entirely sure if this leads you to what you are looking for, however, it does give you a workflow to be able to order the posts by class and output them based on class. I hope this helps

Comment: That gave me the values sorted correctly like this `1234912445679124` when i `echo`ed  `$classes[$row['class']][] = $row['title'];`, But at `foreach` Everything got multiplied. How can i fix the last part?