# SQL row foreach multiplation

Tags: php

Using on this table

```
 [         POSTS         ]
  | id |   title  | class |
  |----|----------|-------|
  | 1  |   4567   |    2  |
  | 2  |   1234   |    1  |
  | 3  |   9124   |    1  |
  | 3  |   9124   |    3  |
  ________________________
```

This code

```
    $statment= $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE id = :id AND class in (1,2,3) ORDER BY class ASC");
$statment->execute([':id' => $id]);


  $classes = array();
  while($row = $statment->fetch()){
  if(!isset($classes[$row['class']])){ $classes[$row['class']] = array(); }
  $classes[$row['class']][] = $row['title'];
}


    foreach($classes as $key => $class){
   echo "Class Value: ".$key;
   foreach($class as $title){ echo "<a>".$title."</a>"; }

}
```

When i put the `foreach` code, Every value gets the $key, But the `echo "Class Value: ".$key;` is supposed to appear once, Then all the values that has `$key` appears and it, But instead the $key is multiplied & When the classes that has for example class = 1, is more than 3, Everything starts to break.

Supposed to be

```
$key:
ROW VALUE 1
ROW VALUE 1
ROW VALUE 1
```

What happens

```
$key:
ROW VALUE 1 [id = 1]
$key:
ROW VALUE 1 [id = 2]
$key:
ROW VALUE 1 [id = 3]
```

When there is more than 3 rows with value 1

```
$key:
ROW VALUE 1 [id = 1]
$key:
ROW VALUE 1 [id = 1]
$key:
ROW VALUE 1 [id = 2]
$key:
ROW VALUE 1 [id = 3]
```

This code was an answer for a previous question i asked here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43054136/7490349

Comment: `ORDER BY class ASC AND id = :id` that should have clearly thrown an error here. The `ORDER BY` goes last and the `AND` is part of the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh, Yes, I have it correctly at my code, just typed it here wrong.

Comment: if the question is about not duplicating entries, use DISTINCT and/or GROUP BY.

Comment: How come the code shows `echo "Class Value: ".$key;`, while the output is `ROW VALUE XX [id = XX]`? If you're asking a question, please make sure you give us the correct output

Comment: @AlonEitan It is not my code as i mentioned at the end of the question, But that why i'm asking about it here, I really don't understand the `foreach` part  here

Comment: This question doesn't make sense, so I can't understand it too - You iterate over the rows returned from the query  and you save it to an associative array where the `class` is the key and the value is an array with all the `title`s. Next you iterate over that array, outputting the `key` of each element, and then you output all the values (`title`s) as links. But it's not what the output say so I can't help you